# Copy elision of overlapping objects

Tags: c++, object, polymorphism, c++14, copy-elision

Reference: [Copy Elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

This can only apply when the object being initialized is known not to be a potentially-overlapping subobject:

```
struct C { /* ... */ };
C f();
 
struct D;
D g();
 
struct D : C
{
    D() : C(f()) {}    // no elision when initializing a base-class subobject
    D(int) : D(g()) {} // no elision because the D object being initialized might
                       // be a base-class subobject of some other class
};
```

If the compiler can make out the memory layout of a non-overlapping object (such as of a primary data type) to elide copy and instead construct the object at its destination, why can't it do the same for overlapping objects as well? What is the limitation at the system level that would make it not possible for the compiler to do such copy elision?

Answer (score 0):

> why can't it do the same for overlapping objects as well?

Because the size of the object would be wrong.  In the case of

```
D() : C(f()) {}
```

the `sizeof(D)` can be larger than `sizeof(C)` and if it is then you can't elide the base class as then there is no room for the derived part in the elided base object.

With

```
D(int) : D(g()) {}
```

You get the same thing in the other direction.  If `D` is a base class of another object then eliding `D(g())` would mean that the object that actually gets created is a `D` and not whatever inherited it and if it is larger than you are in trouble.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your explanation. I would like to think that there would be clear demarcation in memory with respect to the base and derived segments of a polymorphic class object. This being so, wouldn't it be as straightforward for the compiler in constructing the base segment in memory by means of copy elision, just as in the case of say a primary data type object such as int?